# How to create a python package inside a SageMaker?

Tags: python, module, jupyter-notebook, package, amazon-sagemaker

Python packages can be created easily by having a **init** module and a combination of other modules, then we can import a function from one module to another. Now the question is can the same thing be done in Jupyter notebook? Like can all the modules (instead of being .py file being a .ipynb file. The motivation for this question is, can we create a python package inside a SageMaker? By package I mean init and bunch of other modules and a higher level module to call other modules.

Answer (score 0):

SageMaker Notebook instances run on a linux environment, you have access to the file system of the instance and you can create Python packages if you'd like.

I work at AWS and my opinions are my own.